# Law of Large Numbers - IID Assumption

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

My first question here! I was doing some probability review and was just wondering why exactly we need the IID assumption for the law of large numbers to work? Intuitively it makes sense of course, but I can't really put it in words; what exactly would fail if the sequence we are summing up is not IID. Thanks,

Comment: As an extreme case of non-IID, suppose that $X_i=X$ for all $i$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but then how would it fail? Wouldn't any size of sample average give the expectation?

Comment: Oh okay I think I got it, the expectation is not necessarily X, thanks! @AndréNicolas

Comment: There are ways to weaken the usual assumptions, including the assumption of independence. But in the extreme case I mentioned in the comment, the law fails quite spectacularly.  If we perform an experiment once, and out of laziness copy down the result $1000$ times, the sample mean will not approach the population mean.